# how can i convert from php curl to java

Tags: java

I am looking to try  convert curl to JAVA code. cURL code in php work perfect but in java theres porblem this is code php

```
$urlt="http://api.xxxxxxx/xxxxx";
        $apikey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        $camp="id";

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urlt);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('apikey' => $apikey, 'apif' => 'ge', 'camp' => $camp));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

            curl_close ($ch);
```

and this is my convert to java

```
String apikey="xxxxxxx";
        String camp="17";
        URL url = new URL("http://xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        con.setRequestMethod("POST");


        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        String postData = "apikey"+apikey+"apif=ge"+"camp"+camp; // I need somthing like this 
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(postData.length()));

        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes(postData);
        output.close();


        int code = con.getResponseCode(); // 200 = HTTP_OK
        System.out.println("Response    (Code):" + code);
        System.out.println("Response (Message):" + con.getResponseMessage());


        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        int c;
        StringBuilder resultBuf = new StringBuilder();
        while ( (c = input.read()) != -1) {
            resultBuf.append((char) c);
        }
        input.close();

        return resultBuf.toString();
```

and this is the out put

Response    (Code):200
Response (Message):OK
API KEY REQUIRED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not encoding your parameters correctly. You're missing an `=` and the `&` separators:

```
"apikey="+apikey+"&apif=ge"+"&camp="+camp
```

If there's a way of having the library do the encoding for you, as you do in the CURL example using an `array(...)`, that's usually a lot safer.

Comment: I convert post to this 
  String postData = "apikey"+apikey+"&apif=ge"+"&camp="+camp 

but the still same problem

Comment: You need to pay careful attention to each and every character here, they're all important. `"apikey="` not `"apikey"`.

Comment: righte the  character and another probelm I wa add  con.setRequestProperty("Content-type", String.valueOf(postData.length())); 
thas wrong thnaks again

Comment: If this worked, mark it as accepted. If you've got other problems that's fine, but be sure to break those out as separate questions so they get the attention they need.